# How to split matrix and send each line separetly

Tags: matlab

Hello I create matrix example below. And now I have to send it to my serial port, problem is that. I can send only first line properly. Other lines are together. I tried to put fprintf behind for function but with same result. So I have to probably split matrix and then send it.

Matlab code

```
 x=[]; 
    neg = 0;
    for a=1:3
        neg = neg - 1;
        if (neg < -5)
            neg = -1; %//wrap around
        end
        x = [x; [randi([0 9], 1, 5) neg]];
        a = num2str(x);
        fprintf(b,a);
    end
```

This is what it does

```
1  5  4  0  3 -1
1  7  3  5  1 -2
6  2  6  6  7 -3
```

But it sends me this

```
0  5  8  6  1 -1
03    54    89    61    18  --12
036      543      891      614      184   ---123
```

Comment: Can you explain properly? You can show us the input and the expected output, for example.

Comment: At the start only missing: b = Bluetooth('HC-05', 1);
fopen(b);  And its create array of numbers as you can  see in first example. (This is what it does). And now I have to send it to my serial port in same format. So my arduino has to show same lines with same numbers. But when I leave fprintf(b,a); function where I got it. It sends me numbers together only first line is in correct form: example(But it sends me this). I have to send each line separetly when I placed disp function behind fprintf(lines are doubled).In fact, program runs on more than 3 times.

Comment: When you assign `x`, you're concatenating the new random values with the previous values. Therefore, they print out concatenated.

Comment: Because I have to add negative number at the end. So what should I change?

Comment: You're adding a negative number to the end of 5 random numbers, and then concatenating all of that with the previous `x`. Apparently that's not what you want. So don't concatenate with `x`.

Comment: I have to create 5 rnadom numbers and at the end negative numbers I don't know another way how to do it and then send it to my arduino

Comment: You're doing this: `x = [x; [randi([0 9], 1, 5) neg]];`. Do this: `x = [randi([0 9], 1, 5) neg];`. That way, you won't have the results previously stored in `x` concatenated to the new results. Also, if you respond directly to someone, it is helpful if you ping them like @beaker so that they are notified that you have responded.