# How to create an array and then send it to arduino

Tags: matlab

I have to create this array (example below) and then send each line to my arduino separetly.

```
Example
    7     0     2     0     0    -1
     8     6     3     9     0    -2
     4     3     7     7     1    -3
     4     4     6     7     7    -4
     2     6     6     1     1    -5
     4     9     3     5     2    -1
```

Matlab program which created this array

```
b = Bluetooth('HC-05', 1);
fopen(b);
x=[]; neg = 0;
for a=1:6
   neg = neg - 1;
   if (neg < -5)
       neg = -1; %//wrap around
   end
   x = [x; [randi([0 9], 1, 5) neg]]; %//add new row of random numbers to x
fprintf(b,a);
   disp(x);
end
disp('End');
disp(x);
```

The problem is that when I put fprintf function inside for it sends me only first line in correct form others all together. Output arduino:

```
0  5  8  6  1 -1
03    54    89    61    18  --12
036      543      891      614      184   ---123
etc.
```

Disp in for function show that program runs more than 6 times.

```
    7     0     2     0     0    -1
           7     0     2     0     0    -1
           8     6     3     9     0    -2
           7     0     2     0     0    -1
           8     6     3     9     0    -2
           4     3     7     7     1    -3
etc.
```

Disp in the end show data in correct form.

```
End
         7     0     2     0     0    -1
         8     6     3     9     0    -2
         4     3     7     7     1    -3
         4     4     6     7     7    -4
         2     6     6     1     1    -5
         4     9     3     5     2    -1
```

So I think I got 2 options. Create array different way. Or in the end of the program split whole array and then send each line separetly. But I don't know how to do it. So can you guys help me I'm really desparete.

Comment: `fprintf` in Matlab and for device do not perform the same operation. Have yout tried to specify the output string format, as stated in the [doc of serial fprintf](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/serial.fprintf.html)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split matrix and send each line separetly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36815208/how-to-split-matrix-and-send-each-line-separetly)

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36801319/how-to-send-string-to-the-serial-port-5-times